# Error while using Julia code : type - had no field -

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am using Julia for my research. And this is what I am using :
https://augustinas1.github.io/MomentClosure.jl/dev/tutorials/using_momentclosure/

I am going to run exactly same example code in the above website. But then, I got a error message like this :

```
using DiffEqBase.EnsembleAnalysis

means_SSA = timeseries_steps_mean(sol_SSA)
plot!(means_SSA, lw=2, labels=["SSA μ₁₀(t)" "SSA μ₀₁(t)"], linestyle=:dash,
      linecolor=[1 2], background_color_legend=nothing, legend=:bottomright)
```

```
type DiffEqArray has no field indepsym

Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty
   @ .\Base.jl:38 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\RecursiveArrayTools\VzH8Y\src\vector_of_array.jl:439 [inlined]
 [3] apply_recipe(plotattributes::AbstractDict{Symbol, Any}, VA::RecursiveArrayTools.AbstractDiffEqArray)
   @ RecursiveArrayTools C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\RecipesBase\z10lo\src\RecipesBase.jl:300
 [4] _process_userrecipes!(plt::Any, plotattributes::Any, args::Any)
   @ RecipesPipeline C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\RecipesPipeline\XxUHt\src\user_recipe.jl:38
 [5] recipe_pipeline!(plt::Any, plotattributes::Any, args::Any)
   @ RecipesPipeline C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\RecipesPipeline\XxUHt\src\RecipesPipeline.jl:72
 [6] _plot!(plt::Plots.Plot, plotattributes::Any, args::Any)
   @ Plots C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\Plots\B5j7d\src\plot.jl:223
 [7] #plot!#193
   @ C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\Plots\B5j7d\src\plot.jl:213 [inlined]
 [8] plot!(args::Any; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, V, Tuple{Vararg{Symbol, N}}, NamedTuple{names, T}} where {V, N, names, T<:Tuple{Vararg{Any, N}}})
   @ Plots C:\Users\tjrgh\.julia\packages\Plots\B5j7d\src\plot.jl:202
 [9] top-level scope
   @ In[62]:4
```

I am using exactly same code, but this error occurs...How can I fix it???

I just copy and pasted the original code, but it does not work. I want to know how to run this example code.

Comment: I couldn't solve the issue, but I did find that [doctests are turned off for this repo](https://github.com/augustinas1/MomentClosure.jl/blob/main/docs/make.jl#L9), so none of the code blocks are certain to run on their own. The snippets might be missing some lines, or they could be outdated.